# React map not showing data on sub route navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

when i navigate to category screen from homepage or another route the data shows fine. but when navigate to a sub route the data doesnt show:

example (works):

```
mysite.com to mysite.com/category/smartphones
```

example (doesn't work):

```
mysite.com/category/smartphones to mysite.com/category/laptops
```

the h3 in categoryScreen displays the title coreclty form the productmatch variable but the map() not looping through the array when navigating to a sub-route.

app.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen'
import CategoryScreen from './Screens/CategoryScreen'
import AboutScreen from './Screens/aboutScreen'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path='/' component={HomeScreen} exact />
      <Route path='/category/:name' component={CategoryScreen} />
      <Route path='/about' component={AboutScreen} />
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

categoryScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import Products from '../data/Products'


function CategoryScreen({ match }) {
    let ProductMatch = match.params.name

    return (
        <>
            <h3>{ProductMatch}</h3>

            <div className="category-products">
                {Products.filter(product => product.SubCategory == ProductMatch)
                    .map((product) => (
                        <Product product={product} />
                    ))
                }
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default CategoryScreen
```

Comment: please pass key attribute to <Product /> component

Comment: have you ever console the value, `console.log(ProductMatch, Products, Products.filter(product => product.SubCategory == ProductMatch))`, what does it show